# CSS grid grid-column span issue

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am working on the span size of a grid-column.

I have this code for my grid-columns:

```
.main_comp:nth-child(n+3) {
  //background-color: yellow;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.main_comp:nth-child(n+3) .bigimg {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
}

.main_comp:nth-childn+(n+3) .blog_art {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  background-color: green;
}
```

The result I am getting is not quite what I want. I thought that:

```
grid-column: auto / span 2;
```

would span each blogart div 2 columns and three of blogart divs would span over all the 6 columns.

[image]

What I would like is something like this for all the divs from number three and onwards:

[image]

I have setup a codepen on [my example](http://codepen.io/lupis/pen/jmWPwR?editors=1100#0) and the issue I have mentioned here starts on line 66.

Comment: You have 6 columns and use `grid-column: auto / span 1;`. Use `auto / span 2` and it will spread. If it breaks anything else specify those cases accordingly. As a general observation, you're abusing `:nth-child()`. It's slow and unreliable (breaks easily, especially in today's web when almost every tiny plugin manipulates DOM on the fly). You're much safer with classes. Also try to avoid `:not()`. It's extremely inefficient (slow).

Comment: thanks for the advice on nth child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to span 2 cols. *(edit similar answer as Naga Sai A, but  with a different approach/selector)*

you may overide your previous rule `.blog_art:not(:nth-child(2))`  with:

```
.bigimg  + .bigimg ~ .blog_art { 
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  background: tomato;/* see us */
}
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KmzXgx?editors=1100#0

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option

Add below class to the blog_art

```
<div class="main_comp">
      <div class="bigimg">image</div>
      <div class="bigimg">image</div>
      <div class="blog_art new">blog art</div>    
      <div class="blog_art new">blog art</div>
      <div class="blog_art new">blog art</div>     
    </div>

.new:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: orange;

}
```

Codepen URL: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NjNaPX?editors=1100